# Steam Error on Xubuntu 16.10

Tags: xubuntu, steam

I installed Steam on Xubuntu 16.10. But when running `steam` from a terminal, I get the following error message:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/rk/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
awk: /home/rk/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You need to install `Steam` from the Ubuntu repos, not from the Steam website. Uninstall your current version and install via `sudo apt-get install steam`.

Comment: @PatrickNegus Disagree, I have recently install Steam in Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Debian and Linux Mint (LTS versions) by downloading the installer from the official website and it worked every time.

Comment: @Davdriver,@Patrick Negus seems to be right in my case.

Comment: @user161151 Well, if it worked and solved the problem for you, just do it. I only said that the .deb package downloaded from Steam official website works, at least to me.

Comment: @user161151 Great, I'll put my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam is very buggy under Ubuntu 16.10/16.04 when installed from the Steam website.

The 32-bit Steam version from the Ubuntu repositories seems to be the most stable across all systems.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install steam
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing libraries and kernel modules. I would either install, or reinstall your graphics drivers for what looks like Intel i965 graphics. 'sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel' is how you install the graphics driver for Intel i965 if that is your graphics card.

The official binary blobs from Intel are located here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads

Comment: I already have `xserver-xorg-video-intel` installed. The official binary blobs link seems to be broken.

Comment: Odd, it works for me. I found it by going to google and searching for 'intel graphics install ubuntu' and it appears as the top result. I've used the website before to install intel graphics drivers on ubuntu. Try that, and please let us know if you have issues.

Comment: my bad, the link is working.

Comment: No problem! Please let us know if you have any issues, and please upvote if this turns out to be the correct answer. Good luck, and have a great day!